# What insect is this? I saw it in my house in Kolkata on 2 April 2018, at 8:00 p.m

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image: I saw it in Kolkata, on 2 April 1]

I saw this insect in my house in Kolkata (India) on 2 April, 2018 after a storm at around 8:00 p.m.  I would like to know what insect it is.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Kolkata the same as Calcutta, India? Also, that looks like some sort of fly to me, but I can't tell you exactly what kind of fly.

Comment: I highly suspect it to be *Austrosciapus proximus*

Comment: Yes, Kolkata is the new name for Calcutta, India.

Comment: Is Austrosciapus proximus found in India?

Comment: @Joyoti I'm not so sure about that, not so much information about them. However I also found out the species of the *Condylostylus* genus are found in India. They seem to be very similar to the one in the picture, but I'm yet to confirm: http://nathistoc.bio.uci.edu/diptera/Condylostylus2.JPG

Answer (score 1):

It is a species of fly, or of the insect order Diptera, insect family Dolichopodidae.  The exact genus and species is uncertain as there are many hundreds of species. See the link below.  You can also search Google images for these names where many similar fly photos can be seen.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolichopodidae

Comment: More specific identification will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would concur with user22542 --> order Diptera: family Dolichopodidae

Supporting evidence outside of wikipedia is on an Australian website. http://www.bowerbird.org.au/observations/35021

I don't suggest them to be the same species, however potentially related as they seem to live in grassy places across the globe.